# How to create and use multidimensional array in Angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I'm from PHP backgroun, and started using Angular recently.
I'm using Angular 6 and need help on creating multidimensional array.
I tried many ways but not working, so please help.

Comment: Hi - Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If Milind Singh's reply was helpful, please consider "upvoting" it.  Otherwise, please post some of the code you've tried - it would definitely help us better understand how best to help you.  Thank you in advance...

Comment: Using reactive form you can create nested array..Take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1cgvdf If you click on add company and add project you can see the expected result..

Comment: @granny, Reactive form is part of angular..For creating array structure it helps.. first you need to know about differences between the forms at https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the js `Object` type for the purpose.

Example:

```
    let myobj:Object = {
      "employees":[
         {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
         {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
         {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
      ]
   };
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: Plz provide a running snippet.

Comment: Updated. Just copy and paste in you file.